# getJSON explanation

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

```
$.getJSON(
        main_url + "tasks/",
        { "task":8, "last":lastMsgID }
```

I don't really know how this works, but I need a URL or something that can get me messages from a shoutbox and this is what the function uses by default. Does it use a URL and if so how do I plug in the "task" and "last" to the URL? Or is it some other method?

Comment: I want to know how this function works. If it uses a URL to get data, then what would it be? I don't know how "task" and "last" are used.

Comment: please elaborate what u want to achieve

Comment: I want to know how, in this jQuery function, "task" and "last" are used.

Comment: have u looked here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also not sure i fully understand what you want, but a quick explanation of what's going on there.  If you check out the [api](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) for getJson you'll see that the first parameter is the url to query from and the 2nd is optional data to send to the server.  So in your case, the url would be `main_url + "tasks/"` the data sent to the server is `{ "task":8, "last":lastMsgID }`

If your `main_url` is something like `www.domain.com` then your whole request will look like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/tasks?task=8&last=xxx
```

where `xxx` is the lastMsgID

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. I thought it might be .php or something but apparently not. Also I was thrown off by the / following tasks ("tasks/"). Using this I got the data I wanted, thanks man.

Comment: ah, ya the trailing `/` on tasks is unnecessary in this case